# bring UIView On top of my model view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have an activity view which is getting added to a subview of main window rootViewController, however there is a need to display the same activity view when there is a model view controller being presented. I am just curious, as of what is the best way to get a uiview, to be presented all the way up in the hierarchy of childViewControllers?

Comment: Modal views are top level views. So it's impossible to place a view on the top of modal views. How about creating a normal view looks like modal views :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new UIWindow with a windowLevel of UIWindowLevelStatusBar. This will keep your activity view on top of every other view except alert views.

```
self.activityWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.activityWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
[self.activityWindow addSubview:activityView];
self.activityWindow.hidden = NO; //or call makeKeyAndVisible
```

Comment: would this work if I have presented a view controller as well?

Comment: Yes it would. The view controller that you are presenting would be in the window **behind** the window that has the activity view.

Comment: awesome it worked as expected, except that now none of my touch events work.. Maybe I have to set hidden to YES?

Comment: well the hidden to Yes worked.. now I have to take care of is the orientation.. urgh!

Comment: Prior to iOS8, there is no built in way to support orientation changes. Listening for the status bar orientation change notification is one approach that works for iOS2+.

Comment: Well the thing is, the orientation is set to landscape by default, but the progress view shows by default in potrait, so I am assuming either I rotate the activityWindow which would adjust that rotation automatically, or rotate the progressView. I think the window rotation should be a better option.

Comment: Many of the open source activity indicators already handle orientation changes. You should look there for examples of how to do it yourself. I've had success by wrapping [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) in a UIWindow singleton.